How to achieve smooth frame rate independent animations
I have the following animation/movement that's a simple physics attraction model:
const steps = 25;
const friction = 0.68;
const target = 400; // Pixels

let velocity = 0;
let position = 0;

function update() {
  const displacement = target - position;

  velocity += displacement / steps;
  velocity *= friction;
  position += velocity;

  element.style.transform = `translate3d(${position}px, 0px, 0px)`;
}


I would like to make it smooth and frame rate independent. This is what I want to achieve:

The animation duration should be approximately the same regardless of the device refresh rate whether it's 30Hz, 60Hz or 120Hz or higher. Small fluctuations in milliseconds are acceptable.
The animation should be smooth on all devices with 60Hz refresh rate or higher.
The animation behavior should remain the same while achieving point 1-2 above.

How do I go about solving this?

What I've tried
I've tried implementing the by many devs praised technique in the Fix Your Timestep! article, which decouples the update process and rendering. This is supposed to make the animation smooth regardless of the device refresh rate:


function runAnimation() {
  const squareElement = document.getElementById('square');
  const fixedTimeStep = 1000 / 60;
  const steps = 25;
  const friction = 0.68;
  const target = 400; // Pixels
  const settleThreshold = 0.001;

  let position = 0;
  let previousPosition = 0;
  let velocity = 0;

  let lastTimeStamp = 0;
  let lag = 0;
  let animationFrame = 0;

  function animate(timeStamp) {
    if (!animationFrame) return;
    if (!lastTimeStamp) lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;

    const deltaTime = timeStamp - lastTimeStamp;
    lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    lag += deltaTime;

    while (lag >= fixedTimeStep) {
      update();
      lag -= fixedTimeStep;
    }

    const lagOffset = lag / fixedTimeStep;
    render(lagOffset);

    if (animationFrame) {
      animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  }

  function update() {
    const displacement = target - position;
    previousPosition = position;

    velocity += displacement / steps;
    velocity *= friction;
    position += velocity;
  }

  function render(lagOffset) {
    const interpolatedPosition =
      position * lagOffset + previousPosition * (1 - lagOffset); // Linear interpolation

    squareElement.style.transform = `translate3d(${interpolatedPosition}px, 0px, 0px)`;

    const displacement = target - position;

    if (Math.abs(displacement) < settleThreshold) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
    }
  }

  animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

setTimeout(runAnimation, 500);
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#square {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
<div id="square"></div>



...however, devs claim that the animation runs smoothly on devices with 60Hz refresh rate but that the animation is stuttering/is choppy on devices with 120Hz refresh rates and up. So I tried to plot the animation curve on different refresh rates to see if there's something obvious that I'm doing wrong, but judging from the graphs, it seems like the animation should be smooth regardless of refresh rate?


function plotCharts() {
  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  function simulate(hz, color) {
    const chartData = [];

    const target = 400; // Pixels
    const settleThreshold = 0.001;

    const steps = 25;
    const friction = 0.68;
    const fixedTimeStep = 1000 / 60;
    const deltaTime = 1000 / hz;

    let position = 0;
    let previousPosition = 0;
    let velocity = 0;

    let timeElapsed = 0;
    let lastTimeStamp = 0;
    let lag = 0;

    function update() {
      const displacement = target - position;
      previousPosition = position;

      velocity += displacement / steps;
      velocity *= friction;
      position += velocity;
    }

    function shouldSettle() {
      const displacement = target - position;
      return Math.abs(displacement) < settleThreshold;
    }

    while (!shouldSettle()) {
      const timeStamp = performance.now();

      if (!lastTimeStamp) {
        lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        update();
      }

      /* 
      Number between -1 to 1 including numbers with 3 decimal points
      The deltaTimeFluctuation variable simulates the fluctuations of deltaTime that real devices have. For example, if the device has a refresh rate of 60Hz, the time between frames will almost never be exactly 16,666666666666667 (1000 / 60).
      */
      const deltaTimeFluctuation =
        randomIntFromInterval(-1000, 1000) / 1000;
      const elapsed = deltaTime + deltaTimeFluctuation;

      lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
      lag += elapsed;

      while (lag >= fixedTimeStep) {
        update();
        lag -= fixedTimeStep;
      }

      const lagOffset = lag / fixedTimeStep;

      const interpolatedPosition =
        position * lagOffset + previousPosition * (1 - lagOffset);

      timeElapsed += elapsed;

      chartData.push({
        time: parseFloat((timeElapsed / 1000).toFixed(2)),
        position: interpolatedPosition,
      });
    }

    const timeData = chartData.map((point) => point.time);
    const positionData = chartData.map((point) => point.position);

    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = 400;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: timeData,
        datasets: [{
          label: `${hz}Hz (with Interpolation)`,
          data: positionData,
          borderColor: color,
          fill: false,
        }, ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          x: { title: { display: true, text: "Time (seconds)" } },
          y: { title: { display: true, text: "Position (px)" } },
        },
      },
    });
  }

  const simulations = [{
      hz: 30,
      color: "yellow"
    },
    {
      hz: 60,
      color: "blue"
    },
    {
      hz: 120,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      hz: 240,
      color: "cyan"
    },
    {
      hz: 360,
      color: "purple"
    },
  ];

  simulations.forEach((simulation) => {
    simulate(simulation.hz, simulation.color);
  });
}

plotCharts()
body {
  background-color: black;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



I'm probably doing something wrong so any help is appreciated! Please note that alternative approaches to the fixed time step with render interpolation are welcome, as long as the animation behaves the same.

Unless you really need to go wild with the animation eventually, I would suggest looking at if you can bake it into a cubic beziér easing curve or just keyframes and let the browser deal with it.

@AKX the reason I choose this type of animation is because it's easy to adapt and change. For example based on user input, I can easily create animations that are proportional to the force applied by a user which will result in movement that feels natural instead of stiff. Easing curves are really hard to reason with in these contexts so I don't think your answer helps.

Check – it was just a suggestion, and if it doesn't apply to your case, I completely understand :)

"This is supposed to make the animation smooth regardless of the device refresh rate:" - requestAnimationFrame is making the animation smooth because it only does precalculations before render (i.e. whenever the screen updates). Can't see having (thread blocking) while loops in your code helping at all.

@RickardElimää measuring the time it takes to finish each update in my code yields a processing time of approximately 0.1 milliseconds at worst. On a device with a refresh rate of 120 Hz I have about 8,33 milliseconds to finish my updates so I don’t think it’s likely that this is the culprit?

In JavaScript you would simply have to have a solution without while loops. Perhaps a web worker may help.

Should the time for the animation be constant, no matter the length, or is the animation time dependent on the length? Why don't you just have a fixed value for X length? Instead of relying on requestForAnimationFrame which doesn't always fire on every screen update.

@RickardElimää, the code I've shared in this question is working as expected in the sense that the animation duration is almost the same regardless of refresh rate whether it's 30Hz, 60Hz, 120Hz or 240Hz. It differs 10-30 milliseconds for an animation that takes 1700 milliseconds which is negligible. However, the only problem with it is that some devs claim that the animation is smooth on 60Hz but stutters/is choppy on 120Hz. Or am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

If you add an animation duration for a certain number of pixels (ex., 500 ms per 100 px), you can probably remove half your code, simply by basing the translation on the timestamp you get from requestForAnimationFrame and by calculating how much is left until the animation should end.

@RickardElimää if the transition was simple and linear like x = x + 10px that would be simple. But since we have friction that slows down the movement that wouldn't work because the velocity changes over time.

Friction would in that case affect the animation time. Just to get my intention clear, I'm proposing that your original solution isn't the correct one to begin with.

@RickardElimää based on your comments I'm not sure what your intention is. Have you read the article https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/ I shared in my question description? It's a well known technique for smooth frame rate independent animations. If you have suggestions that may be of real help instead of cryptical comments, please share a full solution/example by answering this question. I would appreciate that. But just saying that my type of animation (a simple attraction physics model) is wrong and should be replaced isn't helping.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I tinkered with the parameters, saved and plotted all kind of data from the actual animations, made several experiments but couldn't find any problem with the existing code. The physics in the update function is always producing what appears to be an asymptotic convergence to target (stopped at settleThereshold), while the linear interpolation code is surprisingly precise regardless of the relation of fixedTimeStep to the actual screen fps.
The following stackblitz (just a single static html file, containing an inline web worker) allows one to modify fixedTimeStep and target
and compares the interpolated values with a pre-computed (one might say ideal) solution, that is obtained this way: set the update calls to occur exactly at integer multiples of fixedTimeStep (at t = 0, t = fixedTimeStep, t = 2 * fixedTimeStep, ...., until the square reaches the target -- within settleThereshold) and compute the position of the square for each of these points (from 0 to target). Then, the positions at any intermediate time moment are computed using cubic spline interpolation of the whole set.
What I have seen is that the existing solution behaves exactly as expected and the difference between the existing code (linear interpolation) and the precomputed/ideal solution are minuscule, either if the actual monitor frame rate is larger than 1000/fixedTimeStep or lower.
I have tried to detect the jerkiness but mostly failed, except one case that I'll address immediately. I used mostly 60Hz monitors, and a 120Hz tablet, but the strategy I thought to find issues with the interpolation, was to set
high values  for fixedTimeStep, like 1000/30, 1000/10 or 1000/7 (which is
not even a multiple of the 1000/60 interval between calls to animate -> render).
The only jerky animation I see is one that is very natural and easy to overcome:
at the end of the motion, when the movement between two calls to render is much
less than 1px. And for some reason it appears more obviously in Firefox (on Mac).
Thw experiment in the following snippet attempts to do a minimal reproducible example
for this problem, by moving the square by 1/20 px each frame for a total of40px.


const dx = 1/20; // px
const target = 40; // Pixels

const squareElement = document.getElementById('square'),
    runButton = document.getElementById('run');

function runAnimation() {
    let position = 0;

    function animate() {
        position += dx;
        squareElement.style.transform = `translate3d(${position}px, 0px, 0px)`;

        if (position < target) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
        else{
            runButton.disabled = false;
        }
    }
    runButton.disabled = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: bisque;
}

#square {
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
<button id='run' onclick="runAnimation()">Run</button>
<div id="square"></div>



The fact that this appears as a minor issue, is a feature of the physics in update, which makes the
square touch the target very slowly at the end, with sub-pixel movements
that can last for a few seconds.
A possible solution to this is to set a minimum displacement per frame
of let's say minMovementPerFrame = 0.5, and when the algorithm
gets us smaller values than that, change the regime to finalRunMode,
in which at each render call we add no less than minMovementPerFrame.
If we admit that a movement of less than minMovementPerFrame will result
in jerked animation, we don't have a lot of other choices. A solution that would
skip a few frames in order to accumulate displacement until it's larger than
minMovementPerFrame will probably be even more jerky.
The change in velocity regime might be detected in the animation (at least if one
knows to look for it). An alternative would be to change the physics -- the simplest
change I could think of is to use in the update computation a target that is
slightly larger than the actual target, so the actual target is met when the
velocity is a bit larger than that in the region (at the fake target) when it converges
to zero. In any case, the problem seems to be the animation at very low speeds.
The following fork of the previous stackblitz implements this idea. One can see
the square using it, at the end of the run, going slightly in from of the pre-computed
square, and the same seen in the chart.
The following snippet contains that code without the data extraction, charting or the precomputing worker:


let fixedTimeStep = 1000 / 7;
let target = 400; // Pixels

const squareElement = document.getElementById('square');

const steps = 25;
const friction = 0.68;
const settleThreshold = 0.01;


function runAnimation() {
    let position = 0;
    let previousPosition = 0;
    let velocity = 0;

    let lastTimeStamp = 0;
    let lag = 0;
    let animationFrame = 0;

    function animate(timeStamp) {
        if (!animationFrame) return;
        if (!lastTimeStamp) lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;

        const deltaTime = timeStamp - lastTimeStamp;
        lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        lag += deltaTime;
        while (lag >= fixedTimeStep) {
            update();
            lag -= fixedTimeStep;
        }

        const lagOffset = lag / fixedTimeStep;
        render(lagOffset);

        if (animationFrame) {
            animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
    }

    function update() {
        const displacement = target - position;
        previousPosition = position;

        velocity += displacement / steps;
        velocity *= friction;
        position += velocity;
        if(Math.abs(displacement) < settleThreshold){
            animationFrame = 0;
        }
    }

    const minMovementPerFrame = 0.5; // px
    let finalRunMode = false; // enabled after the pixel movement is less than minMovementPerFrame
    let previousInterpolatedPosition = -1;
    function render(lagOffset) {
        let interpolatedPosition;
        if(finalRunMode){
            interpolatedPosition = Math.min(target, previousInterpolatedPosition + minMovementPerFrame);
        }
        else{
            interpolatedPosition =
                position * lagOffset + previousPosition * (1 - lagOffset); // Linear interpolation
            const dx = interpolatedPosition - previousInterpolatedPosition;
            if(dx < minMovementPerFrame && position > target / 2){
                interpolatedPosition = Math.min(target, previousInterpolatedPosition + minMovementPerFrame);
                finalRunMode = true;
            }
        }
        previousInterpolatedPosition = interpolatedPosition;
        if(interpolatedPosition >= target){
            animationFrame = 0;
        }
        squareElement.style.transform = `translate3d(${interpolatedPosition}px, 0px, 0px)`;
    }

    animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

setTimeout(runAnimation, 1000);
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: bisque;
}

#square {
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
<div id="square"></div>



Maybe if someone sees other cases of jerkiness, possibly using the
stackblitz above to set the parameters, so we can reproduce it,
we may be able to address those cases too. I feared initially that
it might happen at the beginning of the motion, when the acceleration
is strong and the non-linearity more obvious, but I never detected
an issue in that region.

Instead of calling your fixed update as many times as needed convert your logic to use an easing function. Then you just need to check when the animation started, what time it's now and you know in which position your object should be no matter when the animation frame callback occurs.


const element = document.querySelector("my-box");
// If you need to convert from (linear) steps on 60Hz to duration
// It's `steps * 1000 / 60`
const duration = 5000; // ms
const target = 400; // Pixels
const start = document.timeline?.currentTime || performance.now();
// Pick your easing function,
// Here it's a super simple ease-in cubic
function ease(t) {
  return t * t * t;
}
function update(now) {
  // 0-1 position on the whole duration
  const delta = Math.min((now - start) / duration, 1);
  const eased = ease(delta);
  // 0-target position
  const position = eased * target;
  element.style.transform = `translate3d(${position}px, 0px, 0px)`;
  if (delta < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);   
  }
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
my-box {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
<my-box></my-box>




@kikon This is what I meant by adding an animation duration. It's so much simpler to handle. +1 on this one.

@Kaiido I don't doubt that your intentions are good, but I think this is really far off in terms of answering the question. Easings aren't event close to behaving like physics simulations, and almost all games out there use physics simulations, not easings.

Try to use the sliding window technique to force your average delta value to be hardware-independent (almost) and oscillate with some average value.


class AvgDeltaWindow {
    #average = 0;

    #frames_pool_size = 0;
    #frames_count = 0;

    constructor(frames_pool_size) {
        this.#frames_pool_size = frames_pool_size;
    }

    get delta() {
        return this.#average;
    }

    add(frame_length) {
        const effective_frame_length = frame_length - this.#average;

        this.#frames_count += this.#frames_pool_size > this.#frames_count ? 1 : 0;
        this.#average += effective_frame_length / this.#frames_count;
    }
}

// tweak length to fit your animation
//
// the bigger the window - the longer it takes to stabilize over some average value,
// but the value itself will be more accurate
const adw = new AvgDeltaWindow(5);

// somewhere in your loop
let last_timestamp = 0;
const velocity = 0.05;
const loop = () => {
    const timestamp = performance.now();
    const value = timestamp - last_timestamp;

    last_timestamp = timestamp;

    adw.add(value);

    // a.delta -> this is your frame length to multiply by velocity
    console.log(value, adw.delta * velocity);

    setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30);
};

setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30);




Thanks. I get the idea of getting the hardware average delta between frames. But simply multiplying the velocity with delta using this physics simulation doesn't yield the same animation behavior on different refresh rates. I think the displacement and friction should be included in the calculations in some way for the math to be correct.

Yes, probably you are right. I had no experience with implementing any physics using this method - only rendering on canvas =)
